# How can I put an actual image in my tabbar? - swift

Tags: swift, tabbar

I have an actual image in rub color(jpg), that I wanne use as a button in my tabbar. But when I use the image, it is just blue.

How can I override this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `imageWithRenderingMode` to get an `.AlwaysOriginal` rendering of the image and use that.